# Convert Multiple fields to DateTimeStamp

Tags: mysql, date

Hi I have a MySql table that contains the following columns;

```
Year Month Day Time Temp
------------------------
2014 12    30  23.5  15.9
2014 12    31  00.0  13.2
2014 12    31  00.5  11.5
```

Data above is in 30 Min (Half hourly records).

```
Structure:
----------
Year   = int(4)
Month  = int(2)
Day    = int(2)
Time   = decimal(3,1)  "decimal 24hrs"
Temp   = decimal(3,1)
```

I need to query the table to return;

```
Timestamp Date/Time and Temp;e.g.
---------------------------------
2014-12-30 23:30:00   15.9 
2014-12-31 00:00:00   13.2 
2014-12-31 00:30:00   11.5
```

I can return the Date portion (and temp), however unable to convert/include the Time.

I am currently using;

```
SELECT concat(`Year`,'-',`Month`,'-',`Day`) AS `MyDateTimeStamp`, `Temp`
FROM `MyTable'
```

I've searched the threads and can not find similar example.
Thank you in advance,
regards
Tony

Comment: why don't you try `sec_to_time()`? (check answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the time, use `sec_to_time()`. You'll need to convert that time to seconds.

**Example:** `23.5` is equivalent to `23:30:00`, so, `23.5 / 24` is the fraction of day equivalent to that time. So: `(23.5 / 24) * 24 * 60 * 60 = 23.5 * 60 * 60` is the number of seconds. Finally:

```
select sec_to_time(23.5 * 60 * 60);
-- Result: 23:30:00
```

So, to get the date/time:

```
select concat(concat_ws('-', `year`, `month`, `day`), ' ', sec_to_time(`time` * 60 * 60));
```

Comment: Hi Barranka, first time I've used this site , not sure how to vote and thank you both Edper and Barranka.

Comment: Accept his answer. His answer admittedly is much better and efficient than mine. GOD bless.

Comment: @TonyDow Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to [read the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). As for the up/down voting: Use the triangle buttons at the left of each post. If an answer to a question you've made works and solves your problem, click on the check mark at the left of the answer to mark it as accepted. This is a "everybody is welcome" place, as long as you follow the simple rules stated in the tour and in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @TonyDow the best way to thank anybody else here is: 1. to upvote the useful posts (and downvote / flag those posts that are not good or require moderator attention), and 2. (even better) contribute with this site: ask good questions and post good answers. That way, this place will remain a "win-win" spot

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `IF()` function and probably `FLOOR()` function, like:

```
SELECT concat(`Year`,'-',`Month`,'-',`Day`,' ', 
FLOOR(`Time`), IF((`Time`/FLOOR(`Time`))>1,' :30:00',' :00:00')) AS `MyDateTimeStamp`, `Temp`
FROM `myTable`
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56eb0/3).

Comment: Unbelievable, that works perfect, you are a legend greatly appreciated.
I tried using Floor, however could not fully understand it's use, this explains it - thank you.

Comment: Oops spoke too early, all that's being returned is 00:00 or 30:00 alternating every second row ?

Comment: Hi Edper greatly appreciated, both yours and Barranka's work. Thank you.